# Laptop connecting to WiFi but not to Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

My friend's laptop is able to connect to the WiFi router. Typing `192.168.1.1` in the browser shows the login page for the router. But he cannot connect to the Internet. This is true on both Windows and Linux (dual booting setup).

There are three other laptops connecting to the Internet via WiFi just fine and his was fine too until this happened all of a sudden. I tried doing a `tracert` from Windows to an external ip. The first hop to the modem is fine but then the packets seem to be getting dropped.  I haven't asked a question here before but this is really weird. If anyone needs any more information I shall post it here.

EDIT :
He can ping my PC wirelessly on the network and logon to the router login change settings on the router and all that stuff. Pinging any external IP fails. That's the crux of the problem.

If his WiFi adapter is damaged how is it connecting to the modem via WiFi?

Posting the contents of `ipconfig /all`.

Windows IP Configuration:

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : praveen-laptop
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : dslhome
                                    dslhome
```

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dslhome
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-21-5D-17-04-AC
Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 07, 2012 10:41:48 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, December 08, 2012 10:41:48  PM
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dslhome
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-64-54-9F-CB
Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 07, 2012 10:41:39 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, December 08, 2012 10:41:39  PM
```

The problem is with the WiFi link.

Comment: please post 'IPconfig /all' from the host.

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Well as you might have noted this occurs on both linux and windows.

Comment: I'm not doing that great with reading comprehension I see... Sorry.

Comment: Can you connect with just LAN connection enabled (i.e. plug in ethernet, disable wifi)?  And is your wifi router (192.168.1.1) really the DNS server?

Comment: yes just LAN works fine but the LAN adapter shows up as a seperate device in device manager . The modem is dropping outbound packets i think.

Comment: what is the status of port 80 on the router forwarding tables?

Comment: Check the router config.  It's likely there is a rule disallowing the packets from the MAC of his Wi-Fi adapter to pass through the WAN side interface.  Start with the Wi-Fi Security tab in the router administration tool.  Chances are your problem lies therein.

Comment: Another possible issue is that your DNS may not be working, but otherwise you are in fact connected to the internet. To check for that issue, try visiting google directly: http://74.125.224.72

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you verify on your SOHO router's administration interface that there is no security rules forbidding external traffic on his Wireless NIC's IP or MAC.

You may also verify the router's internal routing table, it may have broken rules somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting up his DNS server. Go into the network and sharing center. Then open up the properties of his wireless router. Select IPv4 and type in your own DNS servers.

User Google's public DNS

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Comment: I cant ping any external addresses. Only the modem

Comment: Did you change the DNS server yet?

Comment: Yes I did.And I had tried pinging them even before you suggested changing it .

Comment: Well I'm looking at your connections, and it looks to me like you're connecting through a server. Having your default gateway and DHCP server set to the router's IP is normal, but I'm not sure about the DNS, it's usually something else for what I've seen. That's why i made the recommendation. try using an nslookup command i.e. "nslookup www.microsoft.com"

Comment: Having the DNS set up to the router's IP is how every home router I have seen does it. I would try to ping another PC on the network, unless that has been disabled on the wireless links.

Comment: Alright, sorry I forgot. I apologize for the bad advice.

Comment: Pinging another PC on the network works fine . Why is the router dropping outbound packets only from his Wifi Adapter ?? He can see the landing page of the router and login just fine. Weird.

Comment: Does it work fine when it's plugged in through an Ethernet cable?

Comment: Yes but his ethernet adapter shows up as a separate device in device manager so I guess thats not very relevant.

Comment: Name service doesn't relate to the OP's question so don't worry about the DNS.  A lot of SOHO routers perform nslookup on device then pass the result to local nodes using NetBIOS over TCP/IP.  That's what his router is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your internet connection direct to your PC through ethernet.    If that works, you are most likely looking at a router problem.    I have had routers connect to the wireless and give IP addresses and all and still not deliver any internet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the wired network works correctly on praveen-laptop but over Wifi, only local addresses can be reached ?

I would suggest:

- Check with "route print" (windows) and "route -n" (linux) that you don't have some nasty manually set routes that send packets to a wrong default route. This easily happens with some VPNs.
- Check that the IP address is not conflicting with another host on your network. praveen-laptop is in DHCP but another host could have been using .2 or .6 manually for some time and only causing trouble now.
- It could be a limitation in the router. Some older crappy routers will only let you connect a handful of clients at once. Don't laugh, I've seen it more than once.
- Did you try to restart the router ? Mine does weird things when it had too much torrent traffic.
- In the router interface, you usually have a location that lists the active clients, their MAC and their IP. Anything weird ?

If all this fails and you're feeling adventurous, you can use wireshark (on Linux, it's easier) to "sniff" the traffic from a ping to an external IP. You should see where it's trying to go. If the packet leaves with 192.168.1.1 as destination, the problem is on the router's side. Otherwise, it's a clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to ping each other computer that means there is nothing wrong in wireless network however seems like your wireless router wan port is not plugged with ISP modem using a  Ethernet cable or that cable needs a replace.